# Gérondif: include "en" and "vers" or not?

Tags: prépositions, gérondif

In my presentation I would like to have the following title:

> Au-dessus des nuages – **en** regardant **vers** l'avenir d'aujourd'hui et celui d'autrefois – tout ce que vous "devez" savoir

My question is two-fold:

1. do I have to include "en" or do I have to omit it?
2. is it possible to omit "vers", thereby changing the meaning, but still retaining a grammatically valid sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It would be ungrammatical to remove *en* from that sentence. *En + participe présent* is a construction to refer to the circumstance in which one performs the action. Just the *participe présent* by itself doesn't work.
2. Yes, you can remove *vers*. The meaning changes from "looking towards the future" to "looking at the future" but it's still grammatical.

EDIT:
You could remove the *en* and still have a grammatical sentence where the verb following it qualifies *nuages*, but without a dash between *nuages* and the verb. For example

> Au-dessus des nuages obscurcissant le ciel — en regardant vers l'avenir — tout ce que vous devez savoir
>   Above the clouds that darken the sky — looking towards the future — everything that you must know

Comment: I'm French, I don't get why removing "en" would be a mistake. "Marchant vers la forêt, je repensais à toutes ces choses qu'elle m'avait dites". OK, I read somewhere that removing "en" when it's a "gérondif" is a mistake since the XVIIIth century, but still, it's VERY common in literature.

Comment: And on the site of the Académie Française, I found this: http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-peur-va-grandissante . So, to me, you can, and it's even more beautiful, omit the "en".

Comment: You can remove the "en" if you're qualifying *nuages* but then you'd also need to remove the dash, e.g. *au-dessus des nuages obscurcissant le ciel*. I'll clarify this in the reply.

Comment: That's not what I meant. If you write: "Je vole au-dessus des nuages obscurcissant le ciel", "obscurcissant" is a participe présent referring to "nuages": "I'm flying above the clouds that darken the sky". But if you write: "Je vole au-dessus des nuages - obscurcissant le ciel", it's a gérondif without "en", and "obscurcissant" refers to "Je" : "I'm flying above the clouds - darkening the sky" (I am darkening the sky).